# python print((1 - (40 / 100 * 2))) gives 0.19999999 instead of 0.2

Tags: python, rounding-error

As the title says, when I run in python

print((1 - (40 / 100 * 2)))

it gives 0.19999999999996 instead of 0.2.

Why?

I am using python 3.4.3 and ninja-IDE as editor.

Comment: print$(1 - .8)=0.19999999999999996$

Comment: This is the result of [round-off error caused by floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error#Roundoff_error_caused_by_floating-point_arithmetic). In a nutshell: when expressed in binary, $0.8$ has a repeating (and importantly, non-terminating) expansion.

Comment: thank you!! and what is your advice to handle this? so to get 0.2 instead of 0.19999999996?

Comment: You can use the decimal module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: One solution is to [round](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) the answer

Comment: See [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for a more detailed explanation of rounding error.  I'd also recommend [this video](https://youtu.be/PZRI1IfStY0).

Comment: Also relevant: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: If you want to see the exact number that the computer actually works with when you type 0.8, you can do **print("%.310g" % 0.8)** or **format(0.8, '.310g')**; it's 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125.

Comment: @HansLundmark this one still gives me 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 :           from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
print((Decimal(.8)))

Comment: That's because as soon as you type .8 as a number, you're actually working with that 0.80000... thing, and converting it to a decimal doesn't change that. You need to enter it as a **string** to avoid this effect: **print(Decimal("0.8"))**. This is explained in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you this one is working! so your advice would be to use round() everytime I run a division?

Comment: @HansLundmark thank you again! and sorry i didnt read it all :)  it is strange though that something as simple as a division is so complicate to handle in python..    now I understood the error.. but then why  print((10 - 10 * .85)) is working fine, while
print((10 * (1 - .85))) is not ?

Comment: That's because 8.5 is a floating point number, while 0.85 is not (the closest floating point number is 0.84999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375).

Comment: And it's not specific to Python, the same things happen in any programming language that uses floating point (i.e., almost any language that you're likely to come across).

Comment: @HansLundmark ok, but then again why print((1-40/100)) is working and print((1-40/100*2)) is not?? aren't both 0.4 and 0.8 not "precise" numbers?

Comment: Too complicated to explain in a comment. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @arsik87 No. I would say round whenever you're about to print an answer, if you suspect that the answer might be an integer.  Rounding numbers for every division would just increase propogation of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **binary64** (or **double-precision**) floating-point format ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), that most programming languages and math processing units use, consists of a particular subset of the rational numbers. For example, $1$ and $1/8$ are floating-point numbers, but $1/10$ or $\sqrt2$ aren't.

To be more specific, the floating-point numbers in the interval $[1,2)$ are precisely the $2^{52}$ evenly spaced numbers
$$
1
,\quad
1+\varepsilon
,\quad
1+2 \varepsilon
,\quad
1+3 \varepsilon
,\quad
\dots
,\quad
2 - 3 \varepsilon
,\quad
2 - 2 \varepsilon
,\quad
2 - \varepsilon
,
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varepsilon &= 2^{-52}
= \frac{1}{2^{52}}
= \frac{1}{4503599627370496}
\\
&= 0.00000\,00000\,00000\, 2220446049250313080847263336181640625
\end{aligned}
$$
exactly, or $\varepsilon \approx 2.22 \times 10^{-16}$ approximately.
So the next floating-point number after $1$ is
$$
1 + \varepsilon
=
1.00000 \, 00000 \, 00000 \, 2220446049250313080847263336181640625
.
$$
If you ask the computer to calculate this number, by typing `1 + 2.0 ** -52` into a Python shell, it will get this result (exactly) internally, but it will lie a little and only print the approximation $1.0000000000000002$. And actually if you type `print(1 + 2.0 ** -52)` it will lie even more and print the value $1.0$. To get the computer to print the exact value, you can for example write `format(1 + 2.0 ** -52, ".310g")`.

The floating-point numbers in the interval $[\tfrac12,1)$ lie twice as densely spaced, with the distance $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, so they are precisely the $2^{52}$ evenly spaced numbers
$$
\tfrac12
,\quad
\tfrac12 + \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,\quad
\tfrac12 + 2 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,\quad
\tfrac12 + 3 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,\quad
\dots
,\quad
1 - 3 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,\quad
1 - 2 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,\quad
1 - \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
,
$$
The number $0.8$ is not one of these numbers; the floating-point number closest to $0.8$ happens to be
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \tfrac12 + 2702159776422298 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{2}
\\ &
= 0.8000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
,
\end{aligned}
$$
so this is the exact number that the computer will be working with when you type `0.8` (or `40/100*2`).
The difference between this number and $0.8$ is
$$
\delta = 0.0000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
\approx 4.44 \times 10^{-17}
,
$$
which turns out to be exactly four tenths of the distance between adjacent floating-point numbers in that interval, $\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \approx 1.11 \times 10^{-16}$.

The floating-point numbers in the interval $[\tfrac14,\tfrac12)$ lie twice as dense again, with a spacing of $\varepsilon/4$, and in the interval $[\tfrac18,\tfrac14)$ the spacing is $\varepsilon/8$, and so on.

Now, when you type `1-0.8`, the computer takes the floating-point numbers $1$ and $0.8+\delta$ and subtracts them, getting (exactly) the floating-point number
$$
\begin{aligned}
x
&= 1 - (0.8+\delta)
= 0.2-\delta
\\&
= 0.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
,
\end{aligned}
$$
but when printing the result it lies a little and says $0.19999999999999996$.
Why doesn't it say $0.2$? The answer is that $x$ is the floating-point number closest to $0.19999999999999996$, so if you were to continue the computation by typing `0.19999999999999996` it would use exactly the number $x$, just as if you had stored that value in a variable, whereas if you type `0.2` the computer would use the floating-point number closest to $0.2$, which is not $x$ but the floating-point number two notches above $x$,
$$
x + 2 \cdot \tfrac{\varepsilon}{8}
= 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
.
$$
(Remember that the spacing between floating-point numbers in the interval $[0.125, 0.25)$ is $\tfrac{\varepsilon}{8}$.)
So the computer gives a simplified result which is good enough that you can recreate the actual (floating-point) result from it.

On the other hand, the floating-point number closest to $0.4$ is
$$
0.4 + \frac{\delta}{2}
= 0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
,
$$
where the error is only half of the error for $0.8$, since $0.4$ lies in the interval $[0.25,0.5)$, where the floating-point numbers are twice as densely spaced as in the interval $[0.5,1)$ where $0.8$ lies. So when you type `1-0.4` the computer will calculate the floating-point number
$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= 1 - (0.4 + \tfrac{\delta}{2})
= 0.6 - \tfrac{\delta}{2}
\\&
= 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
,
\end{aligned}
$$
but as usual it lies a little and gives the simplified result $0.6$, and that's because in this case $y$ is actually the floating-point number closest to $0.6$.

So to sum things up, when doing `1-0.8` you (a) have a cruder approximation to the second term than when doing `1-0.4`, and (b) the result ends up in an interval where the floating-point numbers are more densely spaced, so that they can “pick up” that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the representation and precision issues of floating-point numbers in computer systems. Floating-point numbers are represented in binary rather than decimal in computers. Since binary cannot precisely represent certain decimal fractions, rounding errors can occur.

In your example, the result of 1 - (40 / 100 * 2) should be 0.2, but due to the precision limitations of floating-point numbers, the computed result may have a slight deviation and be displayed as 0.19999999999996.

If you need more accurate calculation results, you can consider using the Decimal type or rounding operations to handle the precision issues of floating-point numbers. For example, you can use the round() function to round the result:

```
print(round(1 - (40 / 100 * 2), 2))
```

This will approximate the result to two decimal places and output 0.2.

The round() function in Python is used to round a number to a specified decimal place or to the nearest whole number. It takes two arguments: the number to be rounded and the number of decimal places (or zero for rounding to the nearest whole number).

Here's an example to illustrate the usage of the round() function:

```
num1 = 3.14159
rounded_num1 = round(num1, 2)
print(rounded_num1)
```

In this example, the variable `num1` stores the value 3.14159. By calling `round(num1, 2)`, we round `num1` to two decimal places. The result, assigned to `rounded_num1`, will be 3.14. The output will be:

```
3.14
```

Similarly, if we want to round a number to the nearest whole number, we can pass 0 as the second argument:

```
num2 = 2.7
rounded_num2 = round(num2)
print(rounded_num2)
```

In this case, the variable `num2` stores the value 2.7. By calling `round(num2)`, we round `num2` to the nearest whole number. The result, assigned to `rounded_num2`, will be 3. The output will be:

```
3
```

The round() function is useful for controlling the precision of floating-point numbers or for obtaining whole numbers when needed in your Python programs.