# Inconsistent math in multiplication or Python's multiplication implementation is at fault?

Tags: python, scientific-notation

Is it wrong to say every number in mathematics is simply a fractional number, and any operation performed on them would always return the same output ?

If not, then please explain why the following `Python` snippet doesn't answer exactly the same

```
me@earth ~ % python3
>>>
>>> 43 * 23
989
>>>
>>> 4.3e+1 * 2.3e+1
989.0
>>>
>>> 4.3 * 2.3 * 1e+2
988.9999999999999
>>>
```

For non coding background people, let me put the above snippet like the following

$43 * 23 = 989$

$(4.3 * 10^1) * (2.3 * 10^1) = 989.0$

$(4.3 * 2.3) * 10^2 = 988.9999999999999$

You can reason as much as you want that these numbers are almost equal when we round up, but why are these not equal ?

Does it has something to do with how `Python` is calculating the answer or is this answer right ?

I have verified from some online calculators as well, the answers from online calculators are giving consistent answers, but I can't wrap my head around why the `Python` is giving this answer

Is math wrong, or Python wrong ?

Obviously, math can't be wrong, but why this behavior ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004

Comment: Ah yes, floating point arithmetic...

Comment: Peter O.’s link provides the answer you want. Unfortunately, closing the question as a duplicate appears to require there to be an answer on math stack exchange rather than stack overflow.

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised with the degree of eloquence with which [Python's own documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) explains that problem.

Comment: This is a very well known problem occuring in every language using decimal expansions. Symbolic calculation can avoid this issue as long as we keep in the rational numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the numbers 4.3e1=43.0 and 2.3e1=23.0 are represented exactly in standard floating-point arithmetic, while 4.3 and 2.3 are not. You can see this if you print the exact underlying numbers using the following little trick:

```
>>> print("%.310g" % 43.0)
43
>>> print("%.310g" % 23.0)
23
>>> print("%.310g" % 4.3)
4.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
>>> print("%.310g" % 2.3)
2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

So when you ask the computer to calculate 4.3 * 2.3, it really does
4.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 *
2.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875,
which equals
9.8899999999999988276044859958347248670811673365659664691426113114491869282574043609201908111572265625 exactly,
but this result gets rounded to the nearest floating-point number, which happens to be

```
>>> print("%.310g" % (4.3 * 2.3))
9.8899999999999987920773492078296840190887451171875
```

(the next floating-point number after that one is 9.8900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 exactly, but that's further away)
and when this is multiplied by 100 you get

```
>>> print("%.310g" % (4.3 * 2.3 * 1e2))
988.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875
```

instead of 989.0.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on more on `the numbers 4.3e1=43.0 and 2.3e1=23.0 are represented exactly in standard floating-point arithmetic, while 4.3 and 2.3 are not`. What do you exactly mean by `standard` and `non-standard` `floating-point arithmetic` ? I think the answer to why 4.3 = 4.299.. and 2.3 = 2.299.. lies in this point. But I don't understand why these values are represented like this, it should've been 4.3 = 4.300 and 2.3 = 2.300. Maybe clearing up these definitions with supporting articles or explanation would be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: By “standard floating-point arithmetic” I mean implementations following the standard [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), more specifically the [double precision 64-bit format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). These are *binary* formats, not *decimal*, which is why some decimal numbers behave “unexpectedly” (to people not familiar with what's going on under the hood).

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3459915/1242) is another answer of mine with some more details of how it works, and if you just google “floating point” you'll find plenty of other explanations.

Comment: If you really need decimal numbers to be handled exactly (which is important in some financial applications, for example), then you should use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module from the Python Standard Library instead.